# Any wordpress plugin to build fonts site?

Tags: wordpress, font-utility

Is there any wordpress plugin to help me create a font gallery with these features:

1. Upload and download fonts.
2. categorize fonts.
3. instant font preview for text

   ?

Comment: There's unlikely to be a plugin that specifically covers this for fonts. I'd recommend breaking down your requirements into parts, and looking for each part separately. One of them would just be users uploading files (with support for font files).